# Problems with location and et al in spanish apa6 BibLatex

Tags: biblatex, apa6

Good morning.

I'm a bit newbie with BibLatex, and having several issues. I'll show you first a little MWE of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend = biber, style = apa]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{andothers={et~al\adddot}}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa6}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{smartand}{1}
\selectlanguage{spanish}

First cite: \parencite{santiago2008patrones}, \parencite{santiago2008patrones}

Second cite: \parencite{mill1869system}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

My bibliography file has the below content:

```
@article{santiago2008patrones,
  title={Patrones, generalización y estrategias inductivas de estudiantes de 3º y 4º de Educación Secundaria Obligatoria en el problema de las baldosas},
  author={Cañadas, María C and Castro, Encarnación and Castro, Enrique},
  journal={PNA},
  volume={2},
  number={3},
  pages={137--151},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Grupo Didáctica de la Matemática. Pensamiento Numérico}
}


@Book{mill1869system,
  title={A System of Logic, Ratiocinative and Inductive: Being a Connected View of the Princilples of Evidence and the Methods of Scientific Investigation},
  author={Mill, John Stuart},
  year={1869},
  publisher  = {Harvard University Press},
  location   = {Nueva York}
}
```

When I compile my files, I get the following:

[image]

Here, I detect, almost, 2 errors.

First one: the first appearance of the first cite should look like `(Cañadas, Castro y Castro, 2008)`, but et al. is shown.

Second one: location of the second cite is not shown in the list of references. In an equivalent document, where I'm using apatite and BibTex, I don't have this problem.

Thanks you very much in advance!

Comment: Your first issue is aleviated quite easily: Use the `mincitenames` and `maxcitenames` options, like so: `\usepackage[backend = biber, style = apa,mincitenames=3,maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}`. Your second issue I do not understand, can you describe what you desired output is more clearly, possibly with an example?

Comment: Unrelated: You can use `main=spanish` in your `babel` options and avoid having to set the document language manually with `\selectlanguage`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @MarkusG., but that also raise a problem. With your approach, second time I use `\parencite{santiago2008patrones}` I get exactly the same result as first time I use it. However, according to APA, just the first time should look with all authors, and from there just the first author with et al. Regarding my second issue, according to APA, location and publisher should be displayed as `Nueva York: Harvard University Press`.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Refering to the author-issue, I should point out that APA requires this type of citation for three to 20 authors: (FirstAuthor et al., Year). So, actually it was already correct as it was in the beginning, which makes sense, because the `apa` already tries to incorporate the current APA guidelines as closely as possible. BTW: If you load `babel` with the spanish option, there seems to be no need for the `spanish-apa6` package.

Comment: Seventh edition (APA)  style for book and book chapter references:  **Do not include the publisher location.** https://apastyle.apa.org/blog/publisher-locations-in-book-references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is correct APA style according to the 7th edition of the manual (from 2019). See https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/author-date, https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/elements-list-entry and https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/book-references.

That's what you get from a current version of `biblatex-apa`'s `style=apa,`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{andothers={et~al\adddot}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{santiago2008patrones,
  title     = {Patrones, generalización y estrategias inductivas de estudiantes
               de 3º y 4º de Educación Secundaria Obligatoria
               en el problema de las baldosas},
  author    = {Cañadas, María C and Castro, Encarnación and Castro, Enrique},
  journal   = {PNA},
  volume    = {2},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {137--151},
  year      = {2008},
  publisher = {Grupo Didáctica de la Matemática. Pensamiento Numérico},
}
@Book{mill1869system,
  title      = {A System of Logic, Ratiocinative and Inductive:
                Being a Connected View of the Princilples of Evidence
                and the Methods of Scientific Investigation},
  author     = {Mill, John Stuart},
  year       = {1869},
  publisher  = {Harvard University Press},
  location   = {Nueva York},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{smartand}{1}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
First cite: \parencite{santiago2008patrones,santiago2008patrones}

Second cite: \parencite{mill1869system}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ca˜ nadas, M. C., Castro, E. & Castro, E. (2008). Patrones, generalización y estrategias inductivas de estudiantes de 3º y 4º de Educación Secundaria Obligatoria en el problema de las baldosas. PNA, 2(3), 137-151.//Mill, J. S. (1869). A System of Logic, Ratiocinative and Inductive: Being a Connected View of the Princilples of Evidence and the Methods of Scientific Investigation. Harvard University Press.]

The behaviour you want is 6th-edition APA style (from 2009), which you can get from `biblatex-apa6` with the `style=apa6,` option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa6]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{andothers={et~al\adddot}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{santiago2008patrones,
  title     = {Patrones, generalización y estrategias inductivas de estudiantes
               de 3º y 4º de Educación Secundaria Obligatoria
               en el problema de las baldosas},
  author    = {Cañadas, María C and Castro, Encarnación and Castro, Enrique},
  journal   = {PNA},
  volume    = {2},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {137--151},
  year      = {2008},
  publisher = {Grupo Didáctica de la Matemática. Pensamiento Numérico},
}
@Book{mill1869system,
  title      = {A System of Logic, Ratiocinative and Inductive:
                Being a Connected View of the Princilples of Evidence
                and the Methods of Scientific Investigation},
  author     = {Mill, John Stuart},
  year       = {1869},
  publisher  = {Harvard University Press},
  location   = {Nueva York},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{smartand}{1}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
First cite: \parencite{santiago2008patrones,santiago2008patrones}

Second cite: \parencite{mill1869system}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Canadas, M. C., Castro, E. & Castro, E. (2008). Patrones, generalización y estrategias inductivas de estudiantes de 3º y 4º de Educacion Secundaria Obligatoria en el problema de las baldosas. PNA, 2(3), 137-151.//Mill, J. S. (1869). A System of Logic, Ratiocinative and Inductive: Being a Connected View of the Princilples of Evidence and the Methods of Scientific Investigation. Nueva York: Harvard University Press.]

---

Note that in either case you won't be needing and should not be having the line

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa6}
```

A line like `\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}` was needed in old versions of `biblatex-apa` back when it implemented 6th-edition APA style. But that line has not been necessary since November 2017. A line with `\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa6}` has never been necessary, since the first version of `biblatex-apa6` was released after November 2017.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your explanation @moewe . However, my code apparently doesn't recognize apa6: `! Package biblatex Error: Style 'apa6' not found. l.15145 \RequireBibliographyStyle{\blx@bbxfile}`

Comment: @Á.Garzón Did you install `biblatex-apa6`? What TeX system do you use? TeX Live or MikTeX?

Comment: I thought yes, but I noticed that no, so I've downloaded the folder from https://ctan.org/pkg/apa6?lang=en and put its files inside my execution folder. Now the error is `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. l.512 \DeclareDelimAlias[np
                           textcite]{finalnamedelim}[parencite]{finalnamedelim}`. I'm using MikTeX.

Comment: @Á.Garzón The error means your system is too old. Never download packages from CTAN, **always install via your TeX system (MikTeX Console in your case)**. First make an update via the MikTeX Console (in both admin and user mode if you have a multi-user setup), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864. Then install `biblatex-apa6` via the MikTeX Console.

Comment: Wow, thanks you, I didn't know about install and update with MikTeX Console. I've update my packages and install `biblatex-apa6`, however, now I have the following error: `Sorry, but /Users/agarzon/bin/pdflatex did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
/Users/agarzon/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/miktex/log/pdflatex.log`.

Comment: In the log file appears: `FATAL pdflatex - Bad parameter value.
 FATAL pdflatex - Info: parameterName="font_mem_size"
 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries/MiKTeX/TeXAndFriends/include/miktex/TeXAndFriends/TeXMFMemoryHandlerImpl.h
 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 105`

Comment: @Á.Garzón That sounds like an issue with MikTeX. You may want to report this at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Comment: Thanks for your help @moewe . Finally I got some problems with MikTeX Console, so I decided to uninstall all and install MacTex, so now everything works fine.

Comment: @Á.Garzón If the answer solved your problem, you may want to consider upvoting and/or accepting it (https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to show that the question is resolved.